# Shuffle using cryptography without either party knowing box contents

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, shuffle

I am looking for a way to shuffle an array of known values (like a deck of cards) between two clients who don't trust each other, in a way that can be verified by both parties, and no advantage can be gained.

So far I am thinking...

```
for each item in array:
  A tells B random number to use (Ra1) <~ prevent B from using pre-calculated password
  B creates secret random number, and shows hash to A <~ can prove this number is used
  B adds his own secret random number (Ra1+Rb1) <~ prevent A from using pre-calculated password
  B encrypts a random array value using the combined password (Ra1+Rb1), removing from the stack
  B gives encrypted value to A
  A re-encrypts the value <~ prevent B from recognizing his package later
  A stores at random index in new array of unknown items

A shows the full array to B <~ B can be confident that the array will not be tampered with
A does not know what is in each package, nor does B
B can now choose a package for himself, and A can then provide the password for that package, allowing B to recognize his package, and know the contents.
A can also choose a package, and request the key to unlock it form B.

After all transactions are agreed, and secrecy is no longer required, all secrets are revealed by both parties, who can both then verify the contents of the boxes
```

This all seems overly complex to me - and I can't imagine how to make it work for A, B and C in such a way that no party needs to be trustworthy, or reliable (might not provide keys later - interfering with transactions between other parties).

### Summary

Ideally, I need an algorithm to shuffle a deck of cards, between two untrustworthy parties, in such a way the deck, and the cards can be verified later by all parties, so long as there are at least 2 interested parties providing each other their secrets at the end.

Comment: What is this?Research?What security requirement does this address?

Comment: *"B can now choose a package for himself, and A can then provide the password for that package"* - Your idea is nearly correct, but there is an issue here.  If neither A nor B can distinguish between the cards, how can A know which password to provide for that card?  This is the reason the protocol below *(see my answer)* requires a commutative encryption, and is also why it requires **two** encryption steps from each player - one to prevent both players from knowing which card is which, and one to allow individual decryption of the cards.

Comment: You will get a better answer on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off-topic?  It is a perfect question for this site.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft me neither, I thought it was a good question, and I am sure I got a very good answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the famous [Mental Poker Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker#Shuffling_cards_using_commutative_encryption).  One solution involves [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative) encryption *(ie. E<sub>1</sub>(E<sub>2</sub>(M)) == E<sub>2</sub>(E<sub>1</sub>(M)))*.

From the wiki article:

> 1. Alice and Bob agree on a certain "deck" of cards. In practice, this means they agree on a set of numbers or other data such that each element of the set represents a card.
> 2. Alice picks an encryption key A and uses this to encrypt each card of the deck.
> 3. Alice shuffles the cards.
> 4. Alice passes the encrypted and shuffled deck to Bob. With the encryption in place, Bob cannot know which card is which.
> 5. Bob picks an encryption key B and uses this to encrypt each card of the encrypted and shuffled deck.
> 6. Bob shuffles the deck.
> 7. Bob passes the double encrypted and shuffled deck back to Alice.
> 8. Alice decrypts each card using her key A. This still leaves Bob's encryption in place though so she cannot know which card is which.
> 9. Alice picks one encryption key for each card (A1, A2, etc.) and encrypts them individually.
> 10. Alice passes the deck to Bob.
> 11. Bob decrypts each card using his key B. This still leaves Alice's individual encryption in place though so he cannot know which card is which.
> 12. Bob picks one encryption key for each card (B1, B2, etc.) and encrypts them individually.
> 13. Bob passes the deck back to Alice.
> 14. Alice publishes the deck for everyone playing.
>       [...]
>       This algorithm may be expanded for an arbitrary number of players.

This allows the cards to be shuffled, without allowing either side to cheat, and without either side knowing what cards the other has *(if you remove the last requirement and only want fair shuffling, the problem becomes much easier)*.

The encryption used must be secure against [known plaintext attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).

Comment: I think this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Although - I am surprised there is not a much simpler way.

Comment: @BillyMoon: That's still an open-question.  Although the problem *(and the solution above)* are over 40 years old, a lot of the research is only from the [past few years](http://www.theory.informatik.uni-kassel.de/~stamer/MentalPoker.pdf).  I think more than just a simple solution, a lot of people would like a *fast* solution - the above solution involves a lot of expensive encryptions and back-and-forth network traffic every time the deck is shuffled or a card is used.  I don't think anyone knows if there is a significantly better solution.

Comment: Interesting problem.  I wonder if there's any simplification for the scenario where the deck has three cards?  It would seem that case should be easier to analyze since there are only six possible permutations.  Unfortunately, since permutations are not commutative, it's not quite clear what sort of "commutative encryption" would be most appropriate, and how much extra information that would require.  My guess would be that the commutative encryption function should probably be a six-way permutation (which would effectively be a permutation of the three-way permutations).

Comment: @supercat: Permutations are not encryption; remember, an encryption must have a key.  More importantly, even a "keyed permutation" *(ie. a 2-bit block-cipher)* wouldn't work - the issue is that, after B requests A's key for a card, B could brute-force the key-space to make the card decrypt to whatever he wanted, then lie to A about what the key was.  Thus, even if the input-space only requires two bits, the output-space must still be large enough to prevent brute-force.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: An encryption on a 64-bit block is a permuation among the 2^64 possible 64-bit blocks.  The fact that there are (2^64)! possible encryptions on 64-bit blocks versus six for three-way choices means the latter keyspace can be searched rather more easily (obviously too easily).  Obviously some level of obfuscation will be needed, but for analyzing the problem I would think it interesting to figure out the minimum requirements for the three-card problem.

Comment: I think I might have come up with a faster algorithm to securely shuffle cards between two parties - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53890/i-have-created-an-algorithm-that-should-allow-two-untrusted-parties-to-securely
(Disclaimer: I probably didn't.)

Comment: the `past_few_years` link from @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft comment is dead, but still alive on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20110725212206/http://www.theory.informatik.uni-kassel.de/~stamer/MentalPoker.pdf